# mysql group by field, ignore duplicates in specific column

Tags: mysql

I have a table that records product clicks. For example:

```
productId    ipv4            date           flag
100          32.59.xx.xx     2015-11-29     1
100          32.59.xx.xx     2015-11-29     1
101          32.59.xx.xx     2015-11-29     1
100          64.34.xx.xx     2015-11-29     1
100          64.34.xx.xx     2015-11-29     1
```

I need to group by `productId` but only count one `productId`-`ipv4` pair. I need to ignore any duplicate clicks on a product from the same user.

Expected result:

```
productId    COUNT(*)    SUM(flag)
100          2           2
101          1           1
```

How would I structure the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select productid, count(distinct ipv4), count(distinct ipv4, flag)
from foo
group by productId
```

Check sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac487/1

Comment: i need a more general query, i dont need a solution specific to this example. i need to grab all fields in that group, not just the count. for instance, a SUM of another field

Comment: Then please provide appropriate data. Unless you give us generic enough data, I cannot give you generic solution.

Comment: yes that is what im looking for, i need to brush up on how distinct works